# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cleverhans.utils_keras' in Colab

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory, cleverhans

I used the following to install `cleverhans` in `Colab`:

```
!pip install -qq -e git+http://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans.git#egg=cleverhans
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/src/cleverhans')
import cleverhans
```

And it seems to work good. Then I use the following:

```
from cleverhans.utils_keras import KerasModelWrapper
wrap = KerasModelWrapper(network)
```

And I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-42-bf6d85d04ab3> in <module>()
----> 1 from cleverhans.utils_keras import KerasModelWrapper
      2 wrap = KerasModelWrapper(network)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cleverhans.utils_keras'
```

Answer (score 0):

Module `cleverhans.utils_keras` is a part of [cleverhans_v3.1.0](https://github.com/cleverhans-lab/cleverhans/blob/master/cleverhans_v3.1.0/cleverhans/utils_keras.py). [The subdirectory](https://github.com/cleverhans-lab/cleverhans/tree/master/cleverhans_v3.1.0) has its own `setup.py`, i.e. it's its own separate package. Install it with the command

```
!pip install -U "git+https://github.com/cleverhans-lab/cleverhans.git#egg=cleverhans&subdirectory=cleverhans_v3.1.0"
```

Comment: Thanks @phd! I think you have to add ! before the pip (!pip). I succeeded to install as you mentioned but I still get error: 10 # Assignment rather than import because direct import from within Keras and 
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphKeys